# using CASE in SQL with update statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a case statement something like this. Can someone help with the syntax

```
UPDATE A
CASE WHEN ATTDESC = 'ABC' THEN SET A.DESC = PG.VAL + ' - ' + LD.DESC + ' - ' + GH.PL3NAME
     WHEN ATTDESC = 'DEF' THEN SET A.DESC = PG.VAL + ' - ' + LD.DESC + ' - ' + GH.PL3NAME
END
FROM ATTR A, PRODUCT PG, Global GH, Look LD
```

Comment: A `CASE` is not an `IF`. What rdbms(f.e. MySql, Oracle or SQL-Server) are you using?

Comment: its SQL.. really need help with this ASAP very badly :(

Comment: on a second thought, can i use if else here?

Answer (score 0):

A CASE expression doesn't control flow; it returns a single value.  So something like this:

```
...
SET [DESC]=CASE [ATTDESC] 
  WHEN 'ABC' THEN PG.VAL + ' - ' + LD.DESC + ' - ' + GH.PL3NAME
  WHEN 'DEF' THEN PG.VAL + ' - ' + LD.DESC + ' - ' + GH.PL3NAME
  ELSE [DESC]
END
FROM 
...
```

Comment: sorry i dont get you

Comment: cant we use set in the THEN clause??

Comment: No, that's exactly what I meant by controlling flow.   You cannot put the SET in the THEN clause.   The THEN clause can only be used to return a single value.

Comment: there are two different description columns --- i just updated my question to be clear

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer with the two description columns.